How to inactivate Print when launching a notebook from another notebook?
I am launching a notebook from another notebook:
NotebookEvaluate[
    FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "path-to-notebook"}]]];

The latter contains some Print[...] codes. I want to suppress them. I have tried the combinations
Inactivate[NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "path-to-notebook"}]]],Print]

However, it did not work. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Once again, you didn't take even a second to search this site for prior questions ...

This question is similar to: Suppress Print[ ]s?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Namely: Block[{Print = Identity}, NotebookEvaluate[...]].
